# How to hide decimals on JS?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to show the years I've been working through a JS, but I don't know how to hide the decimals. Can anyone help?

```
var DayDiff = function (start) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    start = new Date(start).getTime();

    return Math.floor((now - start)/ 86400000);
};

document.write("" + DayDiff('2000-04-28')/ 365);
```

Result apears 16.01095890410959 and I just want 16 to appear.

Also, any ideas on how to show a number and add 100 only after 6 months?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Did you try Math.round() or floor()

Comment: Math.round works! Thank you progrAmmar!

Comment: Note that *dayDiff* can be `(Date.now - new Date(start))/8.64e7`, but it will only be an approximation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Use [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), *returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.*

You are returning `floored` value in the function but again after `division`, you will get `floating-number`. Apply `Math.round` over the value returned after division.

```js
var DayDiff = function(start) {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  start = new Date(start).getTime();
  return Math.floor((now - start) / 86400000);
};

document.write("" + Math.round(DayDiff('2000-04-28') / 365));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toFixed()` like

```
console.log(232312.34.toFixed());
```

If you are always going to divide by `365` then you method could be written as

```
var DayDiff = function (start) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    start = new Date(start).getTime();
    var res = (now - start) / (86400000 * 365);
    return res.toFixed();
};

document.write(DayDiff('2000-04-28'));
```

However, if that's not the case, then you need to call `toFixed()` at the final result site like

```
var DayDiff = function (start) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    start = new Date(start).getTime();
    var res = (now - start) / (86400000);
    return res; 
};

document.write( (DayDiff('2000-04-28') / 365).toFixed() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.floor() Method as below code

```
var DayDiff = function (start) {
var now = new Date().getTime();
start = new Date(start).getTime();
result=((now - start)/ 86400000);
return result;
}
document.write("" + Math.floor(DayDiff('2000-04-28')/ 365));
```